# SSD (Single shot detection) or Yolo implementation with Object tracking in swift

Tags: swift, coreml, yolo

I am trying to detect and track object using SSD or Yolo framework in swift. Object Detection is done but i am unable to track the object once it is detected. Needed Help.

Answer (score 2):

Object tracking isn't a feature of SSD or YOLO. They treat each new frame as completely different.

Just because you detected an object in frame N and the "same" object again in frame N+1, doesn't mean SSD/YOLO understand that this really is the same object. They have no concept of temporal coherence.

The simplest thing to do is to use the Vision framework for tracking an object once it has been detected with SSD or YOLO. See the `VNTrackObjectRequest` class.

There is also some sample code from Apple that shows how to use Vision for object tracking.

Comment: a. YOLO once + VNTrackObjectRequest b. YOLO every X frame. which one do you think would have better performance and accuracy? thanks